# Calculating the theoretical frequency response and static gain of a filter

Tags: filter, transfer-function, gain, low-pass, frequency-response

I'm trying to calculate the theoretical frequency response and static gain of this low-pass filter. As far as my knowledge goes, calculating them using experimental means would be simple, but how would one calculate the theoretical values?

The equation I'm trying to use is:

[image]

Here RC = (15 * 10^3) x (0.01 * 10^(-6)) = 1.5 * 10^(-4)

What values of j and omega would I use?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Alois, I think you have a few serious issues to resolve in your head. **j** is not a variable. It's a constant. It only has ***one*** value. You don't get to ask, *"What value of j ... would I use?"* There is only one value you would use for it. Ever. \$j=\sqrt{-1}\$. So that's problem one. Problem two is that \$\omega\$ is your **x**-axis. It takes on all those values, though most would focus on the positive real-numbered values. And that's equally well-defined. You probably need some time with other students in a little get-together to help clear these things up.

Comment: \$\omega\$ is angular frequency = \$ 2 \pi f\$, where f = frequency. Jonk covered what j is which means having to deal with complex arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

If you got there you've done most of the work. *j* is simply the imaginary unit *i* (in electrical engineering *i* usually represent the current so *j* becomes the imaginary root).

Omega is actually the *pulsation* of the signal, in rad/s, which is simply a fancy name for the frequency: multiply the Hertzs by 6.28 and you get omega to plug in the formula.

Be careful since the result will be a complex number (obviously, given the presence of *j*): it will be most useful in polar form to obtain gain and phase; if you convert the gain in dB you can directly make a Bode plot.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have basically already calculated your result, **I assume** that by *theoretical frequency response* you mean *magnitude frequency response*, i.e. a variant of the frequency response that is not complex-valued.

In general: the *frequency response* \$G(f)\$ (complex-valued) is composed of the *magnitude frequency response* \$|G(f)|\$ and the *phase response* \$\varphi(f)\$ (each real-valued):

$$G(f) = |G(f)| \cdot e^{j \varphi(f)}$$

So, in your case, if $$G(f) = \frac{1}{1 + j 2 \pi f R C}$$ (I am using the technical frequency \$f = \frac{\omega}{2 \pi}\$ here) you will get the magnitude frequency reponse simply by: $$|G(f)| = \left|\frac{1}{1 + j 2 \pi f R C}\right| = \frac{|1|}{|1 + j 2 \pi f R C|} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + (2\pi f R C)^2}}$$

This is what you can put into Matlab for example (or whatever software you prefer):

```
Npoints = 1000;
f = logspace(0,6,Npoints);
R = 15e3;
C = 0.01e-6;
Gmag = 1./sqrt(1 + (2.*pi.*f.*R.*C).^2);
loglog(f, Gmag);
grid on;
xlabel('f [Hz]');
ylabel('|G(f)| [1]');
```

resulting in a plot like this:

[image]

Of course, the phase response can be determined and displayed in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say \$\omega\$ is at 1/RC, you get 1/(1 + i), the calculation would go as follows:

[image]

This is the famous -3dB bandwidth at 1/RC rad/s and the -45 degrees of phase shift. You have to repeat this calculation at many frequencies so using a tool such as Matlab or Mathematica would come in handy.

You can study Bode Plots, that are a pictorial representation of the transfer function's gain and phase. The first diagram shows gain (dB), the second one shows phase(deg). x-axis is frequency in rad/s for both:

---

Using Mathematica:

```
f = TransferFunctionModel[1/(1 + 15 10^3 0.01 10^-6 s), s];
BodePlot[f, GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

```
TransferFunctionPoles[f]
```

gives {{{-6666.67}}} which is nothing but 1/RC. Divide this by \$2 \pi\$ to get 530.5 Hz. This is the frequency where the gain of your circuit will be half of what it was at let's say 10Hz. (You have assumed the gain to be 1, why?) If you keep increasing the frequency of the input signal, the gain will keep rolling off as shown.

Answer (score 0):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica) to solve this problem. When I was studying this stuff I used the method all the time (without using Mathematica of course).

Well, we are trying to analyze the following [opamp-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fohyQI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_2=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4\tag1$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Now, using an [ideal opamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Ideal_op_amps), we know that:

$$\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-=\text{V}_1=\text{V}_2:=\text{V}_x\tag3$$

So, we can rewrite \$(2)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_5}
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

Hence, we can solve for the transfer function:

$$\mathcal{H}:=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{V}_\text{i}}=\frac{\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)}\tag5$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
V1 = Vx;
V2 = Vx;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I2 == I3 + I4, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I1 == V1/R2, I3 == V2/R3, 
   I3 == (V3 - V2)/R4, I4 == V3/R5}, {I1, I2, I3, I4, Vx, V3}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> Vi/(R1 + R2), I2 -> (R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3 R5), 
  I3 -> (R2 Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3), 
  I4 -> (R2 (R3 + R4) Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3 R5), Vx -> (R2 Vi)/(R1 + R2), 
  V3 -> (R2 (R3 + R4) Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3)}}
```

My equation was also confirmed using [LTspice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTspice).

---

When we want to apply the derivation from above to your circuit we need to use [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) (I will use lower case function names for the functions that are in the (complex) s-domain, so \$\text{y}\left(\text{s}\right)\$ is the Laplace transform of the function \$\text{Y}\left(t\right)\$):

- $$\text{R}_2=\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\tag6$$

So, we can rewrite the transfer function as:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\cdot\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\right)}=\frac{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3\left(1+\text{C}\text{R}_1\text{s}\right)}\tag7$$

Now, when working with sinusoidal signals we can use \$\text{s}:=\text{j}\omega\$ (where \$\text{j}^2=-1\$ and \$\omega=2\pi\text{f}\$ with \$\text{f}\$ is the frequency of the input signal in Hertz). So, we get:

$$\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=\frac{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3\left(1+\text{C}\text{R}_1\text{j}\omega\right)}=\frac{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3\left(1+\text{C}\text{R}_1\omega\text{j}\right)}\tag8$$

So, the absolute value if given by:

$$\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3\sqrt{1+\left(\text{C}\text{R}_1\omega\right)^2}}\tag9$$

And the argument is given by:

$$\arg\left(\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)=-\arctan\left(\text{C}\text{R}_1\omega\right)\tag{10}$$

---

Using your values, we get:

- Absolute value:
  $$\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+\frac{9\omega^2}{400000000}}}\tag{11}$$
- Argument:
  $$\arg\left(\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)=-\arctan\left(\frac{3\omega}{20000}\right)\tag{12}$$

Comment: The question is "What values of j and omega would I use?"